# Angular 6.10.0 - @Directive and Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive, angular-forms

This is my `@Directive`

```js
/* Imports */
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][myLabel]'
})
export class MyDirective {

  lastValue: string;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInput($event)
  {
    var start = $event.target.selectionStart;
    var end = $event.target.selectionEnd;
    $event.target.value = this.myService.format($event.target.value);
    $event.target.setSelectionRange(start, end); // Preserve the cursor position
    $event.preventDefault(); // A new event will be fired below

    // Avoid infinite loop
    if (!this.lastValue || (this.lastValue && $event.target.value.length > 0 && this.lastValue !== $event.target.value)) {
      this.lastValue = $event.target.value;

      // Must create a new "input" event since we have changed the value of the input, if not, there are no change detected in the value
      const evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      evt.initEvent('input', false, true);
      $event.target.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
  }
}
```

On a 'normal' angular form `<input>` are restricted by my directive

```html
<!-- Expected behaviour works perfectly -->
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" #form=ngForm>
  <input myLabel type="text" ... >
</form>
```

But when it comes to ReactForms my directive isn't applied on the `<input>`

```html
<!-- @Directive not applied -->
<div *ngSwitchDefault [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <input myLabel type="text" ... />
</div>
```

I couldn't find an answer on the web about **How to apply a directive on a ReactForm?**.
I know I should use a `Validator` but my `@Directive` already exists and creating two formatting rules will duplicate logic (how to format inputs) which doesn't seem clean...

*EDIT: My Directive is well declared in `app.module.ts`*
*EDIT2: Provide directive content*

Comment: Adding a host listener to a reactive form control is indeed ugly and not clean. What is the stuff that goes here? Give us insight if you want help. + you can extract the validation and use it in the template driven form AND the reactive form. You should generally stay away from using template driven forms, as they were just provided to make migrating Angular 1 apps to Angular 2+ apps easier

Comment: @finki My problem is part of a huge apllication, every form is template driven except one...
That's why I'm asking a solution for this particular ReactForm tbh. Would lose more time switching to a template driven and reactform is cleaner ;)

Comment: Of course it's cleaner :) regarding your directive implementation: I'm pretty sure a Validator alone can not cover all your functionality because it's doing more than validating. The fastest solution imho would be create a validator for the visualization and observe the valueChanges of the FormControl (https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) -> your logic from the onInput host listener would go in there

Comment: @finki that's what I was looking for, I suggest you to post it in an answer so I could close the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution imho would be create a validator for the visualization and observe the valueChanges of the FormControl:

```
form.get('inputName').valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{
    // Code from your onInput @HostListener
});
```

The validator would go with the form initialization:

```
this.form.group({ inputName: ['initialValue', yourValidator]});
```